# Angular 2 - Injecting a component created by a HTML selector

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am trying to access a component that has been created using a selector within some HTML.  I was under the impression (wrongly it seems) that providers would look for an existing instance and provide that when injected into another component, but obviously I am misunderstanding the hierarchical provider creation process.

In the following, I have a component, which uses a selector within its template HTML to create an instance of TopLevelComponent.

I am trying to access that TopLevelComponent by creating a provider and using DI to push that instance through the constructor.

(Apologies if this code is not perfect, I have just put together a quick example.)

```
@component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<top-level-component></top-level-component>',

    directives: [TopLevelComponent],
    providers: [TopLevelComponent],
})
export class MyApp {

    constructor( private topLevelComponent: TopLevelComponent) {

    }
}

@component({
    selector: 'top-level-component',
    template: '',
})
export class TopLevelComponent {

    constructor() {
        console.log('CONSTRUCTED A TopLevelComponent...');
    }

}
```

But, instead of getting one instance of TopLevelComponent passed to my component I get two (as evidenced by the two logs of 'CONSTRUCTED A TopLevelComponent...' present in the debug log).

If I remove 'private topLevelComponent: TopLevelComponent' from the constructor, I only get one instance of the component, but I don't seem to be able to get hold of this.

So I have two questions

- How do I use DI to pass in the instance of the selector created component to the constructor of other components

or

- If I don't include `<top-level-component></top-level-component>` in the app HTML, how can I inject that HTML into the app so it renders correctly?

And a third

- If both of the above are possible, which is the recommended method?

I was thinking @ViewChild would be the right method, as there will(!) only be one instance of this component, but as it's injected into a number of different components, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Can you please provide a Plunker that demonstrates what exactly you try to accomplish?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Here's the Plunker showing what I'm trying to do - https://embed.plnkr.co/J3G1VBDW0p4FGovLBnI7.   As you can see 'CONSTRUCTED An InjectingComponent...' is printed out twice.  I am trying to pass the instance of 'InjectingComponent' created by '<component-to-inject></component-to-inject>' into 'ReceivingComponent', but instead I am getting hold of a seperate component.   Given that InjectingComponent could be passed to multiple other components (rather than just ReceivingComponent as in this example) I didn't think ViewChild would be suitable.

Comment: I already mentioned that adding a component to `providers` is useless. You also can't inject a sibling, only an ancestor. See my updated answer for a possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a component to `providers: [...]` then the component is treated like a plain class. If DI finds such a provider when `TopLevelComponent` is requested it creates an instance of the component class `@Component(...)` decorator is ignored.

If a component is listed in `directives: [...]` DI will find them as components and directives if they were instantiated because of matching selectors.

**Update**

```
  <component-to-inject #source></component-to-inject>
  <component-to-receive [injectedComponent]="source"></component-to-receive>
```

with

```
export class ReceivingComponent { 

  @Input() injectedComponent: InjectingComponent;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.injectedComponent);
  }      
}
```

Comment: I will put up a Plunker example now, but in the mean time (as I am not sure I understand your comment), if I remove 'providers: [TopLevelComponent]' and just leave in 'directives: [TopLevelComponent]' then I get the following exception - 'ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for TopLevelComponent!'

Comment: If the component is a child of the current component, injection won't work. Then you have to use `@ViewChild()` or `@ViewChildren()`. DI only looks for ancestors.

Comment: Great, thanks.  Passing the injected component as an input to the recieving component was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a reference to a component that is present in your template, you can use the @ViewChild annotation.

```
@ViewChild(TopLevelComponent)
private myTopLevelComponent:TopLevelComponent
```

this will give you the first instance of TopLevelComponent that angular finds in the corresponding template.

if you have multiple components of the same type but you want to find a certain one you can use a local template variable.

```
@ViewChild('templateVariableName')
private myTopLevelComponent:TopLevelComponent
```

your html template would need to look like this:

```
<top-level-component #templateVariableName></top-level-component>
```

and finally:
if your want to find all components of the same type, you can use the @ViewChildren annotation.

```
@ViewChildren(TopLevelComponent)
private topLevelComponents:QueryList<TopLevelComponent>
```

this will give you a list of all TopLevelComponents in your template.

**Why are two instances created in your example?**

Using the providers array and asking for that class to be injected in your constructor tells angular to create a instance of your component class. 
The second instance gets created, when angular parses your template.

Note that the instance you get injected via the constructor is not the same as the one that is present in your template. Any changes you make to the injected instance won't be reflected on screen.

To get the correct instance, you need to follow the steps i provided above.

Answer (score 0):

angular2 passes list of services in providers. Service is reusable code snippet.

Basic service example that can be used in any directive/Component.

```
imports ...

    @Injectable()
    export class MyEmpService {
        getAllEmployees() {
            // hit database
            // return employee list
        }
        getEmp(id: number) {
            // hit database
            // return employee data 
        }
}
```

Component is a directive with view. Angular2 passes list of components in directives. Any component from the list can be used in the component. Again it is reusable code but with view.
Simple example:
EmployeeComponent.ts

```
imports...

@Component({
    selector: 'my-emp',
    template: `
        <button (click)="getEmpList()">Get All Emp</button>
        <button (click)="getEmp(2)">Get Emp</button>
        <div>
            {{result | json}}
        </div>
    `,
    providers: [MyEmpService]
})

export class EmployeeComponent{
    private result:any = '';
    constructor(private myEmpService: MyEmpService) { }

    getEmpList(){
        this.result = myEmpService.getAllEmployees();
    }
    getEmp(id: number){
        this.result = myEmpService.getEmp(id);
    }
}
```

AppComponent.ts

```
imports...

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>Main Component</h1>
        <my-emp></my-emp>
    `,
    directives: [EmployeeComponent]
})

export class AppComponent{ }
```

Comment: In my case I don't have a service, but a previously selector based created component that I want to pass to another component

Comment: AppComponent is using EmployeeComponent